# Is there any way to get diagrams from google cache?

Tags: cache

I would like to know if I could get diagrams from this [cached web page](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:tXZYF0futEoJ:sce.uhcl.edu/michel/ppt/Intro.ppt%20&cd=4&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=in).I tried downloading the original file(.ppt) of the cached version but it doesn't open.While I look at the cached page I can only see text but no diagrams.

Is there any way to retrieve UML diagrams(like class diagrams) from this cached web page.